# JList is not displaying when DefaultListModel is changed using AddElement

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am implementing a program for a Component Design course and am currently struggling with what should be simple use of a Jlist. The program draws shapes and should display them in a JList in a ScrollPane in the BorderLayout.West of the frame.

The current program shows the ScrollPane but will not display objects I add to the shapeListModel like it should. I am wondering it I am missing something or if something is flat out wrong with my code. Currently this is all the code that partains to the JList creation, assigning, and updating.

```
    //Class Variable Declaration
protected ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
private JScrollPane shapeScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
private JList<String> shapeList;
protected DefaultListModel<String> shapeListModel;

    //Creation of JList objects and what not
shapeListModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();

    //This element is added aimply to try and get one to show up on my JList, 
shapeListModel.addElement("SERIOUSLY FRUSTRATED"); 
    //It does not just so you know

shapeList = new JList<String>(shapeListModel);
shapeList.setModel(shapeListModel);

    //Adding JList to ScrollPane and setting size
shapeScrollPane.add(shapeList);
shapeScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,600));

//Clarifying JList actions  
shapeList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
shapeList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
shapeList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
shapeList.addListSelectionListener(this);**

    //This is called everytime a new shape is created and adds it to the Arraylist
    //shapes and the DefaultListModel shapeListModel
shapes.add(newShape);
shapeListModel.addElement(newShape.toString());
```

I apologize for my poorly formatted question a few moments ago. I have been stuck on this for approximately 4 hours, the last two hours spent searching for answers online. I am now resulting to asking anyone if they see an issue within the code I have.

Comment: I suspect `shapeList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);` might be part of the problem..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "add" components a scroll pane.  You need to set it's view ports view instead.

Don't do this...

```
shapeScrollPane.add(shapeList);
```

Do this...

```
shapeScrollPane.setViewportView(shapeList);
```

Check out

- [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- [`JScrollPane#setViewportView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29)

Also, this `shapeList.setVisibleRowCount(-1)` scares me to no end.

**Updated**

You also don't need to this...

```
shapeList = new JList<String>(shapeListModel);
shapeList.setModel(shapeListModel);
```

This is more then sufficient...

```
shapeList = new JList<String>(shapeListModel);
```

**Updated**

Also, if this is the same code that was used in a previously closed question...

This `canvas.getGraphics()` terrifies me!!  If your instructor gave you this code, then they shouldn't be teaching you!

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I will take all the input into consideration. Another student pointed out to me I should be using ScrollPane not JScrollPane. 

And Yes, canvas nonsense was from instructor if it is poor code. It isn't necessarily the purpose of the course. I'll bring it up with him though.

Comment: `JScrollPane` is the correct component.  You don't want to be mixing heavy and light weight components together

Comment: Correction, I'll use yours MadProgrammer, the ViewportView, since it works as well and you are quite adamant about mixing components.